# Dynamic Circular progress bar pure CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I am looking for a dynamic circular progress bar in HTML using CSS which will pick values from a text file. The values will be something like this 97.56,2.44. So i want the circular progress bar to display green for the 1st value which in this case is 97.56 and remainder of the circle to be displayed in red.

I read up a few tutorials online but all of them had static values in the CSS. The reason I am looking for such a dynamic progress bar is because my python script is running on a cron job every 5mins and these values keep updating. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If it is server side, how about to use `Django`? JS is for client side, so, I do not think you can access to a local file of an unknown user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 
 percentage=97.56;
 Im not familiar with python Do something like
 assign value to 
    `<div class="progress-bar position" data-percent="echo percentage;" data-duration="1000" data-color="red,green"></div>`

[Dynamic Circular Progress Bar](http://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Dynamic-Circular-Progress-Bar-with-jQuery-CSS3.html)